# Laravel - export db rows to sqlite format

Tags: laravel, sqlite

We have a website based on Laravel 5.3 and a mobile app that can work offline. Laravel is using MySQL database.

I need to synchronize data between web and mobile app. Mobile app would make a request with a timestamp, and API would send all data changed since that timestamp.

My mobile developer said it would be easiest for him to receive the data as a single sqlite database file. So my question is:

is there a way in Laravel to export selected data to valid sqlite format?

Comment: *My mobile developer said it would be easiest for him to receive the data as a single sqlite database file* -- i don't know it's the easiest.. but you can [tell laravel to use sqlite](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#configuration). but for sure, it might expose a lot.. well, i can only suggest try use json or another serialization approach..

Comment: I don't want to use sqlite db in laravel, I want to export data to sqlite format.

Comment: i know. but, you can't export some rows on a whim.. even the best i can find on google search is [this](https://github.com/RealpageLouisville/mysql-to-sqlite).. but seriously, if i were you. i would start from proper serialization rather than db dump. if you post why did you need the sqlite (be it the relation is pretty deep or such), it might be even better, we might able to suggest you a more graceful approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by creating an `Artisan` command that dumps selected tables to sql and then converts it to sqlite using [this script](https://github.com/dumblob/mysql2sqlite)

So the whole code in my command looks like that:

```
exec('mysqldump -P ... login credentials ... tables to export ...'.storage_path('app/export/dump.sql'));
exec('mysql2sqlite '
    . storage_path('app/export/dump.sql') . ' ' 
    . storage_path('app/export/sqlite.db') 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> sqlite format

Laravel got nothing to do with whatever your database server is. All you need to do is to dump your current database as pure SQL (i.e. using phpmyadmin) and import to sqlite database. If needed you can use tools like http://sqlitebrowser.org/ to import your dump and then hand your dev .sqlite binary file which shall work too.

Comment: Yeah, but two things: I need to do it automatically on request form mobile app and I don't need to dump all of my DB, just changed rows.

Comment: Then definitely you need it in format of SQL dump (text). Or you go with own format. There's no binary sqlite format that allows you to merge two databases in one file, so better go with normal queries you can execute (or own data that you parse and based on that you build SQL query and execute